# How to find gradient of a polynomial line in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, machine-learning

I have stored the value of loss and learning rate per epoch in the list. Then plotted them using Matplotlib. After plotting, fitted a polynomial line using **polyfit**. Here, I tried with some dummy values for loss and learning rate in this code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

loss = [7,6,4,4,3,4,2,1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7]
learning_rate = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

plt.plot(learning_rate,loss, color='orange')

draw_polynomial = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(learning_rate,loss, 5))
polyline = np.linspace(1, 16, 50)
plt.plot(polyline, draw_polynomial(polyline), color='purple')

plt.xlabel("Learning Rate")
plt.ylabel("Loss")

plt.show()
```

I got something like this as output:

[image]

As I want to stop when the gradient of this polyline is positive. Therefore, I've to find the gradient of this poly curve. How to do that? How can I know at which point the slope is becoming positive?

Comment: you can only fit the line to points you have calculated, first time you stop at learning rate 6, the fitted curve would go up if using the first 6 datapoints. Find the derivative by sampling 2 points close to each other and subtract the poly-function values, that is what calculus does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `print(draw_polynomial)`, it will display the equation of the polynomial. You can use numpy's `deriv().r` function to get the local minima of the polynomial within the range or bounds of the chart displayed `(1-16)`. I used this local minima value (`8.6860`) to chart the dashed red line, to help verify the solution.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

loss = [7,6,4,4,3,4,2,1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7]
learning_rate = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

plt.plot(learning_rate,loss, color='orange')

draw_polynomial = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(learning_rate,loss, 5))
polyline = np.linspace(1, 16, 50)
plt.plot(polyline, draw_polynomial(polyline), color='purple')

print("Polynomial equation = \n\n", draw_polynomial)

# Calculate local minima
bounds = [1, 16]
for x in draw_polynomial.deriv().r:
    if x.imag == 0:
        if bounds[0] < x.real < bounds[1]:
            local_minima = x.real

print("\nLocal minima = ", local_minima)

# Plot a red dashed line at the local minima
plt.plot([local_minima,local_minima],[1,7], 'r--')

plt.xlabel("Learning Rate")
plt.ylabel("Loss")

plt.show()
```

### Output:

```
Polynomial equation = 

             5           4           3          2
-9.774e-05 x + 0.00351 x - 0.04256 x + 0.2912 x - 1.845 x + 8.548

Local minima =  8.686061318331596
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the points where the polynomial derivative is zero, in the range of interest, with this line

```
roots = [np.real(z) for z in draw_polynomial.deriv().roots 
                        if np.imag(z)==0 and 1<=np.real(z)<=16]
```

In your case the expression value is `[8.68606131833166]` and it's a minimum, in general you loop over the `roots` list, checking if the 2nd derivative is positive (minimum) or negative (maximum) and subsequently take the appropriate action

```
for root in roots:
    second_derivative = draw_polynomial.deriv(2)(root)
    if second_derivative>0:
        # it's a minimum 
        ...
    elif second_derivative<0:
        # it's a maximum
        ...
    else:
        # it's a point of flexure
        ...
```